# Is it possible that AC mains (UK ~230V 50hz) could cause micro stutters under load in modern PC's on potentially noisy home sockets?

Tags: hardware-failure, power, gaming

I am experiencing machine stutters on my PC, after changing every single component 3+ times (every component, yes) and reinstalled operating system over multiple different disks. Yet, they still persist with a sufficient power supply. All drivers reinstalled.

These stutters usually present themselves during processing, i.e. playing a game, or watching YouTube in a web browser for example.

So is it possible—in a situation like this—that AC mains (UK ~230V 50hz) can cause micro stutters under load in modern PC's with potentially noisy mains in a home?

See https://youtu.be/PY5QyRKK0IM

Comment: What possible line of reasoning brought you to that conclusion?

Comment: @Tetsujin So, I would never have assumed this. I have tried every possible diagnostic step to get to where I am now. If you would like to message me personally, I can provide detailed posts of what I have performed thus far. 

The only consistent 'model' of component is a Ryzen 5 1600, and other users aren't reporting this behaviour. It's my third Ryzen 5 1600. My third PSU, 5th motherboard, 5th monitor, 4th GPU, 3rd set of RAM, and 4th SSD. 

It is at the point now where I have followed the required steps to perfection (to usually solve these issue) -- now I am here and told to check AC.

Comment: @Tetsujin this is over multiple operating systems, stock settings, overclocked, and underclocked, fresh installs, every driver for AMD and Nvidia GPU's over the past 2 years, and every BIOS released for each board. SSD firmwares, etc. All software components can surely be ruled out.

Comment: If it was the UK mains, then why aren't the other 40 million UK computer users asking the same question?

Comment: @Tetsujin I appear to have posed my question incorrectly. What I suppose I mean would be - Could *potentially* noisy mains cause such an issue?

Comment: You may be receiving radio frequency interference. As you might guess from my handle and icon, I'm a radio tech as well as a PC tech. Manufacturing, avionics, and medical equipment can emit large amounts of radio frequency energy which can be picked up by the power mains and/or components in your PC. Please describe the environment, reaching out a block in all directions, and your proximity to any airport and radio mast.

Comment: When I sold systems into South and Central America and the Caribbean, customers often requested isolation transformers https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_transformer and voltage stabilizers https://www.quora.com/How-does-a-voltage-stabilizer-work so, where are you? Lundy Island? Knoydart Peninsula? Foyda? Or, are you near a welding or machine shop, places which can put out awful variations in power?

Comment: Exactly what do you mean by "stutter"?

Comment: I'm not an expert at all but I used to get extremely bizarre behavior when using cheap inverters to power laptops.  This was years (Decades) ago and the only things I could imagine is that the laptop powersupply couldn't handle the more squareish waves, the frequency was wrong or there was a floating DC component in the AC.  I could never pin it down and just stopped using cheap inverters.  I'd be surprised if that was your problem but I wanted to say that the power supply CAN cause some strange behavior--but probably not the mains from the power grid.

Comment: I think that this theory is easily verifiable or bust-able by bringing your PC to a relative's/friend's house, coffee shop, or library and performing the same tests. My theory is that you will experience the same stutter regardless of the presence of electrical noise.

Comment: To all people that replied to this: I am in a residential area in London, UK. I don't have the ability to transport this machine elsewhere. At all. Also, please see these posts for further background: https://forums.geforce.com/default/topic/1073706/geforce-1000-series/nvidia-boost-clock-voltage-changes-quite-clearly-causing-stuttering/ and https://community.amd.com/thread/231700

By stutter, I mean, micro freezes in the application.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Please see above post.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Please see above post.

Comment: @BillK Please see above post.

Comment: Is the issue always in CS:GO? Do other games exhibit this?

Comment: What? I don't see any edits to your question?

Comment: @MichaelHampton They meant "comment" not post. https://superuser.com/questions/1374089/is-it-possible-that-ac-mains-uk-230v-50hz-could-cause-micro-stutters-under-lo?noredirect=1#comment2069725_1374089

Comment: What other software are you running? Is it possible that some background app such as AntiVirus is randomly spiking you to obscene CPU usage? McAfee has a live file scanner which randomly fires off and completely eats my i5-6500 cores.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Comments are temporary, some people don't see them at all, so anything relevant needs to be edited into the question.

Comment: All games. Multiple operating systems. I just play CS GO more and notice it more.

Comment: Before it gets much colder, acquire an extension cord https://www.homebase.co.uk/masterplug-proxt-30m-10a-medium-metal-cable-reel_p280627 from HomeBase or B&Q, and run it to a neighbor's socket, to see if you can replicate the problem with someone else's power.

Comment: I really dont have access to that, but appreciate the suggestion. thank you.

Comment: If you can't try your computer elsewhere, another option is to borrow an uninterruptable power supply and connect it between your computer and mains.  It's an easy way to add an extra layer of isolation that frequently clears up power regulation issues.  If you still see the problem with the UPS attached, then it's extremely unlikely that it's caused by your mains power.

Comment: Thank you -- it appears UPS is the final test. If it happens on UPS I have no idea what.

Answer (score 8):

**Short answer:** no

**Long answer:** The PSU converts the 50/60Hz AC into a near-perfect DC, with the remaining ripple being well above (orders of magnitude above) a few Hz. You could of course use an 48VDC PSU and 4 car batteries, but I am convinced, you'd see the same stuttering.

It is much more likely, that the stuttering is part of an interaction between software components, most likely some drivers, or just the hardware not being able to perform the tasks fluently.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I don't know if I am allowed to discuss this here as per the rules of the website, but I would like to know how this could be possible over: 

2 different brands of motherboard (therefore with 2 different BIOS programmers) in which case one model was replaced 4 times. 2 different graphics cards, in which case one model of them was replaced 3 times and 4 different disks. 2 x SSD and 2 x HDD. Windows 10 and Linux Mint.

Of course, fresh installs, all drivers removed and added, etc. It seems to be purely down to the mains, but I cannot be sure based on this answer.

Comment: I appear to have posed my question incorrectly. What I suppose I mean would be - Could *potentially* noisy mains cause such an issue?

Comment: I am convinced, that a very low-quality mains feed could make a computer crash (if the ability of the PSU to smooth things out is overwhelmed), but not stutter and recover

Comment: There's a simple way to test, take your machine else where - a friends house for example, and see if the problem exists. I'm pretty confident it will. Also, did you change the _MONITOR_ ??

Comment: @djsmiley2k Not a possibility, I'm afraid. However, yes, I have changed monitor 5 times, with 8 different cables.

Comment: @EugenRieck then I am stumped with this information.

Comment: @mpw If your question is really about what could cause your stuttering, you should ask a question about the stuttering going into as much detail as possible about what problems you're observing and what steps you've tried. For example, have you checked if the stuttering correlates with CPU temperature?

Comment: Correlation does not imply causation. Did you try a different O/S, i.e. boot Linux from a USB stick and run some stress tests there?

Comment: https://openhardwaremonitor.org/ could be helpful in monitoring CPU temp as suggested two comments above

Comment: @mpw What's your cooling solution and what temps are you getting when these issues come up? It could be poor thermal paste or cooler seating.

Comment: @mpw Have you tried replacing the PSU itself?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz

Please, I know the main causes of stutter. The reason I am asking this is because I have exhausted all other options. You wont believe me, so please see these threads:

1. http://forum.asrock.com/forum_posts.asp?TID=10037&PN=2&title=could-bios-settings-cause-stuttering

2. https://community.amd.com/thread/231700

3. https://forums.evga.com/The-hardest-stutter-to-troubleshoot-m2850576.aspx

4. https://forums.geforce.com/default/topic/1073706/geforce-1000-series/nvidia-boost-clock-voltage-changes-quite-clearly-causing-stuttering/

Comment: @PascLeRasc Please see above post

Comment: @JAB Please see above post

Comment: @AdamLawrence Please see above post

Comment: @mpw So you did replace the PSU.

Comment: Yes @JAB. 3 times. EVERY component.

Answer (score 2):

No.

If your supply was that bad, you'd see either memory errors at least, or hard lockups at worst. You wouldn't get a constant, reproducible error such as 'stuttering' during computation.

You don't mention if you've ever changed the monitor and depending on the monitor and it's sync settings, you maybe seeing screen tearing caused by vsync issues.

To rule out the fact it's the supply, simply take the machine to a friends house and power it on there.

Comment: Sadly not an option to move the machine.

Yes, I have tried 5 monitors, and 8 cables.

It's not screen tearing. VSync on and off causes it, but VSync on causes too much input lag. 

Besides, it's a 144hz monitor. If I sync the frame rate manually, more or less, it still persists. If I use VSync, it persists. If I unlock the full frame rate, it persists.